# Crosswalk error in my meteor app "XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()"

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, chromium, crosswalk

I have added cordova:cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 1.6.1 in my 1.3.2.4 meteor project. When i run my app in my android device, i have this error when i click button/link or tap my screen:

> E/chromium( 7891): [ERROR:xwalk_autofill_client.cc(172)] Not
>   implemented reached in virtual void
>   xwalk::XWalkAutofillClient::OnFirstUserGestureObserved()

I also have this error at launch

> E/chromium( 7891): [ERROR:runtime_javascript_dialog_manager.cc(118)]
>   Not implemented reached in virtual void
>   xwalk::RuntimeJavaScriptDialogManager::CancelActiveAndPendingDialogs(content::WebContents*)

Comment: show you code , may helps

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this,
and I solve it by add this to the activity where xwalkview in , and refer [here](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs/reference/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html)

```
 @Override
   protected void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       if (mXwalkView != null) {
           mXwalkView.pauseTimers();
           mXwalkView.onHide();
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       if (mXwalkView != null) {
           mXwalkView.resumeTimers();
           mXwalkView.onShow();
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       if (mXwalkView != null) {
           mXwalkView.onDestroy();
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       if (mXwalkView != null) {
           mXwalkView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       }
   }

   @Override
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
       if (mXwalkView != null) {
           mXwalkView.onNewIntent(intent);
       }
   }
```

add `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` to application node to open hardware accelaration.